# MySQL - Change Password - shouldn't use old PW

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, compare, workbench

The problem is that I change the password of an mysql-db-user and can use the old password - but that's what I want to forbid.

Example:

- Old Password: "test" (encrypted in DB - how can I compare it with the new PW?)
- New Password: "test" -> should give an error, because it's the same as the old PW

How can I compare the old password with the new one? Or is there an option in the Settings of the MySQL-Workbench? Many thanks in advance!

Edit:
I'm thinking of changing the passwords of the database users who are listed in mysql.user

Comment: How did you change the password? Have you tried running `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after updating the password?

Comment: Yes, I did, but mysql didn't recognize the "not changing" (old PW == new PW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it - and this is an easy solution:

First I ask for the old password of the username and compare the input with the new password the user want to set. If both are same my app throw an error. Example:

Old PW: "test"
New PW: "test" --> Error: Old PW == New PW

Maybe there's an option in the MySQL Workbench - but I didn't find something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly sure of your workflow, but in php, you should be able to do something like

```
$email = $_POST['email'] /*email posted from "password change" page*/

$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$new_password = $_POST['new_password'] /*this is your new password*/

if( $new_password == $result['password']){
    /*password is the same as previous*/
} else {
    /*password is new*/
}
```

The code isn't tested, but should be close if it doesn't work

Comment: I tried to implement it in Java, but the passwords are encrypted - sure why not^^, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` doesn't are you able to create a new database and then compare things that way?